# Only 1 side is rendered

Tags: unity, blender, mesh

I'm trying to get my .blend object into Unity but for some reason I see it differently in Unity than in Blender.

I was trying to solve the problem and someone said that I have to go to the edit mode, then mesh, then change the normals but that is not working for me.

Here is what I mean:
[image: Faces not showing in unity, showing in blender]

Answer (score 2):

`Edit-mode->ctrl-N` (make sure you have the entire mesh selected.)

What is happening is you have normals on one half of the front facing the wrong way so you're getting a backface culling on half of the object. The ctrl-N hotkey recalculates the normals to make them uniform across the surface. To edit a specific normal, you do:

`Edit-mode->N->scroll down to "Mesh Display" on the panel that appears on the right->Select on of the 3 options under "Normals"`

Then you can edit your normals by selecting a mesh-element and then doing `W->Flip-Normals`